# Capturing Crosswalk Cordova webview touch events

Tags: android, cordova, webview, crosswalk-runtime

I'm building a web based Android app using the [Crosswalk Cordova framework](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova.html), and 
I'm trying to capture any touch events that occur on the XWalk webview within the main activity of my app, but so far everything I've tried I can't get the touch events to be triggered during debugging sessions.

Specifically I'm trying to capture a three finger swipe down anywhere on the web view so I can display a settings pane.

Here is what I've got so far in my main activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends CordovaActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());

        // appView is the main xwalk webview setup in parent
        appView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int action = event.getAction();
                // Check for three finger swipe... 
            }
        });
    }

    ....
}
```

I realise I could probably catch the touch event through javascript events that could then trigger the action through a cordova api call, but I'd much rather have this logic within the android app.

I've also tried capturing touch events in `onTouchEvent` method

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    // Check for three finger swipe... 
}
```

But again this method is never triggered.

Any help or ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to get this working by overriding the `dispatchTouchEvent` method defined in `Activity` class. This was capturing the touch event and delegating them to my cordova webview without ever firing my `onTouchEvent`.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    int action = ev.getAction();
    // handle three finger swipe

    super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

I hope this may help someone facing this issue :)

Comment: could you help me in detecting the scroll event.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just FYI you are missing semi-colon after dispatchTouchEvent(ev) :)