# Cannot scroll in a app with CrossWalk Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, webview, crosswalk

I have a application based on [Crosswalk Cordova framework](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova.html), and it's impossible to scroll in it. Is it still possible to tap anywhere but impossible to scroll.
Previously, we were using the "original" webview embedded with Cordova, so Chrome engine in Android 5.0+ and System WebView in the previosu versions, and the scroll was working, so I think it's not a HTML/CSS problem.

I tried to override the "setOnTouchListener()" on the Activity.java of our application like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28229155/capturing-crosswalk-cordova-webview-touch-events) or [there](http://codetheory.in/android-ontouchevent-ontouchlistener-motionevent-to-detect-common-gestures/), but nothing...

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm having a similar problem..

Comment: Yeah, it was just a CSS problem... I don't remember the property 'cause I'm not at home, but try deleting some parts of your CSS.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it already! In my case, only happened after I entered fullscreen mode and hit Android back button to exit it. I found out that the back button was not correctly exiting the fullscreen mode, and some CSS was added when entering didn't get removed. So it was also a CSS problem..